# Implement a message queue for logging in a .NET webapi

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, message-queue, nlog

I have a .NET7 server, with a few webapi, that logs the request and responses to log files with NLog.
I don't want to waste time on the logging, so in the controllers I add the message to a

```
  ConcurrentQueue<LogText> logTextsQueque
```

this way

```
  var logText = new LogText { deviceSerial= deviceSerial, message = message };   
  logTextsQueque.Enqueue(logText);
```

and in the Main.cs I added this loop, that effectively writes the log to disk:

```
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (logTextsQueque.TryDequeue(out LogText result))
                        {
                            LogOut(result.deviceSerial, result.message);
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Error($"C3 Background thread error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }

                }


            });
```

It's a sort of message queue. It seems to be working, but is there something I should be worried about with this simple implementation?

Thanks

Comment: Notice the `while (true)` will cause a single task-thread to do heavy spinning, and use a whole cpu-core constantly when nothing in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog has a builtin message-queue called [AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target), that can be easily enabled in `NLog.config` using `<targets async="true">`:

By default it uses `overflowAction="Discard"` to prevent application failure because of logging issues.

The [AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target) ensures that [NLog Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context) will correctly capture `${threadid}` and will log the threadid of the application-thread (and not the background thread handling the message-queue).

Comment: Oh thanks! I was unaware of this feature and I tried to reinvent the wheel. I moved back to normal logging, but in case I would use this procedure for deferring something else, writing something to db or to disk (adding exceptions management of course), is it correct or is there something wrong in it?

Comment: @MattiaDurli It is a good idea to defer external communication to a background thread, especially when fire-and-forget. Microsoft usually recommends using async Tasks, which works okay when handling user-driven-requests and allows returning task-failures. When wanting to have throttle-limit and retry and failover, then one have to introduce Polly or SemaphoreSlim. When wanting to have back-pressure and batching then one should consider the message-queue. Many books has been written and many fingers/hours has been burned on the alter-of-concurrency.